# How do I fix the error in my IF AND function that has "maybe" more than two conditions

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I am getting an error asking if I am trying to type a formula, but I am not sure what the issue is

=IF(AND(K74="yes",J74">"&S3,J74"<="&S4),$I$74,0)

Condition 1: K74=Yes
Condition 2: J74 between two dates
If true
=I74

PLEASE HELP?!

I tried making it an ifs function but then I dont have enough arguments

I think the issue that there are 3 conditions not two and the solutions I found online focus on two conditions only.

I also tried putting the commas in different places and using semi colons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build two conditions for the between-check without joing them as text:

`=IF(AND(K74="yes",J74>S3,J74<=S4),$I$74,0)`